# Java Bitshift Operation: error converting int to byte

Tags: java, type-conversion, bit-shift

can someone tell me why the following code is throwing the compile error "cannot convert from int to byte"?

```
byte x = 2;  
byte y = (x >> 1);
```

I mean I clearly declared both x and y as bytes, and 'x >> 1' will evaluate to 1 i.e. still be in the range of a byte.
Also when I do something like

```
byte x = -2;  
System.out.println(x >>> 1);
```

I would expect 126 to be the outcome, because I shifted a `0` in the leftmost bit of `b1111 1101`, which is `0111 1110`. But the console is printing '`2147483647`', so it looks like my byte has been converted to an integer before the `0` has been shifted in. Why is that? Please help me out.

Comment: The type of `x >> 1` is `int`. Why? Because the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1) says so.

Comment: See [Java Language Specification paragraph 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because `x >> 1` returns an `int` so you simply need to cast it explicitly to a `byte` as next:

```
byte y = (byte)(x >> 1);
```

Please also note that since it is an `int` operator (or `long` depending on the left-hand operant cf [`§15.19`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) from the specification), all its operands must be of type `int` which means that in your case `x` will be implicitly converted into an `int` too in other words `x >> 1` is equivalent to `(int)x >> 1`